# Good-Turing Smoothing Results

Tags: nlp, smoothing

My implementation of Good-Turing smoothing produced the perplexity numbers below. These don't seem correct, though. Any intuitions as to why?  I am using a corpus of 1,000 movie reviews from NLTK. My implementation seems correct (reproduced below).

```
1gram ppl: 1057.398218919647
2gram ppl: 3262.444941553032
3gram ppl: 68.10224173098685
4gram ppl: 4.542117543343882
5gram ppl: 1.7044134004884632

def good_turing_prob(ngram_occurences,freq_of_freq,total_ngram_count):
    # unseen gram
    if ngram_occurences == 0:
        N_1 = freq_of_freq[1]
        N = total_ngram_count
        return N_1/N
    #ngram is present in model
    else:
        # take closest count if count+1 is not present
        N_c_plus_1 = freq_of_freq[min(freq_of_freq, key= lambda x:abs(x-(ngram_occurences+1)))]
        N_c = freq_of_freq[min(freq_of_freq, key= lambda x:abs(x-ngram_occurences))]
        good_turing_count = (ngram_occurences+1) * (N_c_plus_1/N_c)
        return good_turing_count/total_ngram_count
```

Comment: What are you feeding it as values / what are you trying to estimate? Looking at the values there, it seems like you're actually estimating expected counts of different types of n-grams. The expected counts for any given type 2-gram could be higher because there are more possible 2-grams. Once you get to 5-grams, though each is basically unique. That's just a hunch, though.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't a bunch of unique 5-grams create a higher perplexity? All of my samples are either classic literature or social network samples.

Comment: Expecting to see everything only once or twice is high perplexity, because the only way your model can account for it is by retaining individual examples. Expecting to see everything 3000 times means the number of bits you need to represent the data is lower. Most surprising to me is the 1-gram estimate.